# How to prove that $\frac{d\left(\tan^{-1}x\right)}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ directly using the definition.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

How to prove that $\frac{d\left(\tan^{-1}x\right)}{dx} =\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ using the definition.

I trying to prove some derivatives using fundamental theorems. But no idea of the proof $tan^{-1}x$

Comment: If $x=\tan y$, then you want to prove $1+x^2=\frac{d(\tan y)}{dy}$, i.e. $1+x^2=\frac{1}{(\cos y)^2}$. But this is true by the identity $1+(\tan y)^2=\frac{1}{(\cos y)^2}$.

Comment: It's not clear whether by "using the definition" refers to (a) the definition of the derivative (i.e., you want a proof that uses a difference quotient and takes a limit),  or (b) the definition of $tan^{-1}$ (i.e., you want a proof that uses the fact that $tan ( tan^{-1} (x ) ) = x$  together with the chain rule and the previously-known derivative of the tangent function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $u=\arctan x, u+k=\arctan(x+h)$. This means $\tan u=x,\ \tan(u+k)=x+h$ and $-\dfrac\pi2<u, u+h<\dfrac\pi2$. Note that, by continuity, $h\to 0\iff k\to 0$.

Now the rate of variation can be rewritten as
$$\frac{\arctan (x+h)-\arctan x}{h}=\frac kh=\frac 1{\cfrac hk}=\frac 1{\cfrac{\tan(u+k)-\tan u}k},$$
so that 
\begin{align*}\lim_{h\to 0}&\frac{\arctan (x+h)-\arctan x}{h}=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1{\cfrac{\tan(u+k)-\tan u}k}\\={}&\frac 1{\lim\limits_{k\to 0}\cfrac{\tan(u+k)-\tan u}k}
=\frac1{\tan'u}=\frac1{1+\tan^2u}=\frac1{1+x^2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: This uses a known derivative of the tangent function and does not evaluate that derivative by taking the limit directly of the difference quotient.

Comment: @Dr. MV: Of course. I simply express a difference quotient from another difference quotient. How can you do differently? Maybe you have another definition of $\arctan$?

Comment: Well, you have a difference quotient, that is true.  But you don't prove that its limit is the secant function.  Rather, you just use that known result.  One way to prove this is to use the inequalities $$|x\cos x|\le |\sin x| \le |x|$$for $0\le x\le \pi/2$, which can be obtained without appealing to calculus.  Then, application of the squeeze theorem finishes it off nicely.

Comment: The O.P. did not ask for reinventing the wheel. When you work with $\arctan$, you're supposed  to have heard some facts about $\tan$!

Comment: If your contention is correct, then save a step, don't invoke the tangent function at all, and simply write the difference quotient for the arctangent and state the answer for the limit.  I don't believe that it would be reinventing the wheel to proceed as I mentioned.  If that is too much, then use the well-known limit of $\sin x/x$, etc

Answer (score 2):

We have $y=\tan^{-1}(x)$ if, and only if $\tan(y)=x$, $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$. Applying implicit differentiation to the latter equation yields
\begin{align*}
\sec^2(y)\frac{dy}{dx}&=1\\
(1+\tan^2(y))\frac{dy}{dx}&=1\\
(1+x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}&=1\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{1}{1+x^2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: This is not "using the definition" as OP requested.

Comment: This is the definition of arctan.

Comment: Without using the the chain rule

Comment: @AngeloMark This is the standard proof of this derivative.

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan^{-1}(x+h)-\tan^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x+h-x}{1+(x+h)x}\right)$$

$$\implies\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(x+h)-\tan^{-1}x}h$$
$$=\dfrac{\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac h{1+(x+h)x}\right)}{\dfrac h{1+(x+h)x}}\cdot\dfrac{{\dfrac h{1+(x+h)x}}}h$$

Set $\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac h{1+(x+h)x}\right)=u$

As $h\to0\implies u\to0 $

Answer (score 2):

For any bijective differentiable function $f:I\to J$, calling $g$ the reciprocal function, we have
$$\forall x\in I, g\left(f(x)\right)=x\tag{1}$$
(we have also $\forall x\in J, f\left(g(x)\right)=x.$)
From the definition, we remark that $g$ is differentiable and using the chain rule we get
$$\forall x\in I,\;g'(f(x))f'(x)=1.$$
Therefore, writing $y=f(x)\in J$ (such that $x=g(y)$), we obtain
$$g'(y)=\frac1{f'(x)}=\frac1{f'(g(y))}.$$
If $f=\tan$, $g=\arctan$, with $I=\mathbb R$ and $J=(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$,
it follows that
$$\arctan'(y)=\frac1{\tan'(\arctan y)}=\frac1{1+\tan^2(\arctan y)}=\frac1{1+y^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since several others have already provided a host of ways forward, I thought it might be instructive to present two more.  To that end, we proceed.

---

**METHOD $1$:** Using standard, non-calculus-based tools

In terms of the definition of the derivative, we have

$$\frac{d\arctan (x)}{dx}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x+h)-\arctan(x)}{h} \tag 1$$

Now, using the addition angle formula for the tangent function, $\tan(x-y)=\frac{\tan (x)-\tan(y)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(y)}$, we have

$$\frac{\arctan(x+h)-\arctan(x)}{h}=\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{h}{1+x(x+h)}\right)}{h} \tag 2$$

Now, we recall the basic inequality from geometry

$$|\sin x||\cos^2 x|\le |x\cos x|\le |\sin x| \tag 3$$

From $(3)$ it is easy to see that

$$\left|\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right|\le |\arctan (x)|\le |x| \tag 4$$

Using $(4)$ in $(2)$ reveals

$$\left|\frac{\frac{1}{1+x(x+h)}}{1+\left(\frac{h}{1+x(x+h)}\right)^2}\right| \le \left|\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{h}{1+x(x+h)}\right)}{h}\right|\le \left|\frac{1}{1+x(x+h)}\right|$$

whence applying the squeeze theorem yields the coveted result

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x+h)-\arctan(x)}{h}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

And we are done!

---

**METHOD $2$:** Using the integral representation of the arctangent

One way to define the arctangent is in terms of the integral

$$\arctan (x)=\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt$$

Then, we have

$$\frac{\arctan(x+h)-\arctan(x)}{h}=\frac1h \int_x^{x+h}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt \tag 5$$

Applying the mean-value theorem to integrals to $(5)$, there is a number $x<\xi<x+h$ such that

$$\frac{\arctan(x+h)-\arctan(x)}{h}=\frac1h \frac{1}{1+\xi^2}((x+h)-x)=\frac{1}{1+\xi^2}$$

Then, using the squeeze theorem for $x<\xi<x+h$, we have

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x+h)-\arctan(x)}{h}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

as expected!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can and one that I think answers your question quite precisely.